# Grabing ip address in aspx page for a php website

Tags: php, c#-4.0

I am trying to grab clients IP address who is  requesting my website using the following code:

```
 protected string GetIPAddress()
        {
            System.Web.HttpContext context = System.Web.HttpContext.Current;
            string ipAddress = context.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ipAddress))
            {
                string[] addresses = ipAddress.Split(',');
                if (addresses.Length != 0)
                {
                    return addresses[0];
                }
            }

            return context.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
        }
```

I have this in my c# web service code which resides on the same server where my client side web server code resides  (in this case it is php).

So client makes a requuest to my php website which resides on server 1 .the php wesbite make a request to c# webservice for data which resides on server 1 .The ip address captured in my case is always where my php code resides .Is it because in my case its the php code on the server 1 making request .

Should i be grabbing the ip address in my php code and pass it to my c# web service to log into database .
Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated
Thanks,
Anurag

Comment: Since you PHP code will always contact your service, you should do as you said in last line and grab your client IP in PHP code and pass it to service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP is executed server side so when it makes a request to the c# web service the C# web service will always have a `Request` object reflecting the PHP code that is calling it from the same server.

Yes, you should read the IP address in the PHP code in this case.